# How to calculate/predict width after a browsers zoom?

Tags: css, browser

Specifically, how do I predict/calculate the effect any of the browsers' zoom will have, for example, on width:950px?  Are there any tools I can use to determine the new widths?

edit:
If I have a 950px div that is visually rendered 875px in, say, chrome, I could say chrome reduces fixed widths by approx. 92.1% after one crtl-. (950*.921= approx .875).

Answer (score 0):

Try F[irebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843)

Its an excellent plugin for Firefox, which lets you view variety of parameters.
You could play around with it and it would probably solve your problem.

Comment: I've just downloaded firebug today for this very reason.  Except when I zoom out (ctrl-) on a 950px div, it still says the div is 950px.